# Agreement with an offer or a university proposal or a plan

Tags: verbs

Suppose tow school classmates are talking to each other regarding to the masters' degree theses of them. One starts to complain about one of his university professors who did not agree with his offered plan  / proposal subject. He would possibly say something like the sentence bellow; does it sound natural:

> - My (offer / proposal) was not **accepted**.
> - My (offer / proposal) was not **approved**.

Comment: If you are asking about what the ***person who is complaining*** would say, it would be, "My proposal was **not** accepted (or approved)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general Proposals and Offers are accepted. Here I think I would be emphasising that the professor's opinion was significant and **approval** seems better.

However the school or university will have a formal process, and may well have their own terminology. [For example](https://elliott.gwu.edu/sites/elliott.gwu.edu/files/downloads/acad/advising/forms/graduate_thesis_subject_approval_form.pdf), here the term approval is explicitly used. I suspect that **offer** would not be the term for suggesting a thesis subject. I see the term **Topic Application** used in some examples.

In summary, don't rely on normal use of everyday language when speaking about processes in particular institutions, best to stick to their language.